# Remove prefix before writing file

Tags: java

I have a file name Codex_file001.zip. I wanna remove prefix Codex_ before writing the file. Any help would be appreciated.

```
File f=new File("Codex_file001.zip");
    String s = f.getName();
    String[] splitted = s.split("_");
    File new1 = new File(splitted[1]);
    Files.copy(f, new1);
    f.delete();
```

I want to save this file with name file001.zip.

Comment: try printing splitted[1]

Comment: [String][1].substring(). All you need


  [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: is Codex_  fixed prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
File f = new File("Codex_test.txt");
String fName = f.getName();
String newFName = fName.substring(fName.indexOf("_")+1);
f.renameTo(new File(newFName));
```

You can use substring in combination with indexOf to determine the location of the starting character. And then renameTo to create a new file.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if String contains `_` and then spit, e.g.:

```
private String removeCharsBeforeUnderscore(String input) {
    return input.contains("_") ? input.split("_")[1] : input;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
System.out.println(removeCharsBeforeUnderscore("Codex_file001"));
```

This would work even if String does not have underscore character.

Answer (score 0):

using regex pattern with replaceFirst

```
String test = "Codex_file001.zip";
System.out.println(test.replaceFirst(".*?_", ""));
```

output:

```
file001.zip
```